# Writing Operators as a sum of projectors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, probability

I have what I think to be a simple question, but can't seem to find a direct answer to.  I just want to know if my thinking is correct here. My question is related to writing operators as a sum of projectors.

My specific problem deals with operators represented in the Fock state basis, such as the number operator.  So my example will be from this framewwork.  For a bipartite system, suppose I have an operator $\hat{O}$ given as:
$$\hat{O} = \alpha \hat{a}_1^{\dagger}\hat{a}_1 + \beta \hat{a}_1\hat{a}_2$$

If I calculate the transition amplitudes using the state $| n,n\rangle$, this gives:
$$\langle m,m|\hat{O} |n,n\rangle = \alpha n \; \delta
_{m,n} + \beta\sqrt{n m}\;\delta_{m,n-1}$$

So wouldn't this mean that I can write the operator as a sum of the following projectors?

$$\hat{O} = \alpha n |m\rangle \langle n| + \beta \sqrt{n m} |m\rangle \langle n-1|$$

If I then normalize this by dividing by the sum of the projector amplitudes, would this represent the probability of obtaining each projector?  Namely, the normalized operator is given as:

$$\hat{O}_{\text{normalized}} = \frac{\alpha n |m\rangle \langle n| + \beta \sqrt{n m} |m\rangle \langle n-1|}{\alpha n + \beta \sqrt{n m}}$$

And the two possible outcomes (m,n) and (m,n-1) probabilities are:

$$P_{m,n} = \frac{\alpha n}{\alpha n + \beta \sqrt{n m}}$$

$$P_{m,n-1} = \frac{\beta \sqrt{n m}}{\alpha n + \beta \sqrt{n m}}$$

Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Why would you normalize an operator?

Comment: Furthermore, you don't get probabilities from the operators.  You get them from the *state* of the system.

Comment: I don't know why this question got closed.  It is not a "homework question."  I have been out of grad school for years.  I just wanted to understand something better.  The answers were terrific and helped me understand the broader concept of how post-measurement states work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of misconceptions in the OP.  First of all, there is no reason to "normalize an operator" (unless that operator is a density operator/density matrix, but then it's not an operator representing a physical observable). Secondly, you get probabilities from the expansion coefficients of *states*, not from the operator.  Finally, when representing an operator in terms of projection operators, you have to sum over all possible projection operators.  The details for this last statement are below.

Note that the operator $\hat{O}$ that you've written is not Hermitian, and as such it can represent neither a physical observable *nor* a density matrix, so there's no sense in which we should be talking about probabilities here anyway.

Finally, let's talk a little bit about the language here.  You measure a physical observable $O$ represented by the Hermitian operator $\hat{O}$.  The possible results for the measurement are the eigenvalues of $\hat{O}$.  Assuming that the operator is non-degenerate for simplicity, if we get the value $o$ as the result of the measurement, then the post-measurement state is arrived at by operating with the projection operator $\hat{P}_o = \lvert o \rangle \langle o \rvert$, where $\lvert o\rangle$ is the eigenvector of $\hat{O}$ with eigenvalue $o$. The *probability* of getting the result $o$ depends on the state $\lvert \psi_{\textrm{pre-measurement}}\rangle$ of the system at the time of measurement; this probability is given by
$$
\operatorname{Pr}(o) = \langle \psi_{\textrm{pre-measurement}} |
\hat{P}_o | \psi_{\textrm{pre-measurement}} \rangle
= \lvert
\langle o | \psi_{\textrm{pre-measurement}}\rangle
\rvert^2\,.
$$
Upon getting the value $o$, we know that the state of the system "collapses" to the eigenvector $\lvert o \rangle$. Mechanically, we can write this down as
$$
\lvert\psi_{\textrm{post-measurement}}\rangle
=
\frac{\hat{P}_o \lvert \psi_{\textrm{pre-measurement}}\rangle}
{\sqrt{\operatorname{Pr}(o)}}\,.
$$

This language contrasts with the language in the OP. You don't obtain a projector as the result of a measurement! You obtain a *number* (an eigenvalue of the measured operator), and then you can *use* the corresponding projector to find the post-measurement state.

---

Generally speaking, to represent an operator, you need *all possible* projectors.  To do this correctly, let's insert a couple of resolutions of the identity, i.e.,
$$
\hat{I} = \sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty}\lvert m,n\rangle\langle m,n\rvert\,,
$$
on either side of the operator and simplify:
\begin{align}
\hat{O} =
\sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty}\lvert m,n\rangle\langle m,n\rvert
\hat{O}
\sum_{j,k=0}^{\infty}\lvert j,k\rangle\langle j,k\rvert
=
\sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j,k=0}^{\infty}\lvert m,n\rangle
\langle m,n\rvert\hat{O}\lvert j,k\rangle
\langle j,k\rvert\,.
\end{align}
Then, the matrix element in the middle can be computed as
\begin{align}
\langle m,n\rvert\hat{O}\lvert j,k\rangle
&=
\langle m,n\rvert
\alpha \hat{a}_1^{\dagger}\hat{a}_1 + \beta \hat{a}_1\hat{a}_2
\lvert j,k\rangle
=
\alpha\langle m,n\rvert
 \hat{a}_1^{\dagger}\hat{a}_1
\lvert j,k\rangle
+
\beta\langle m,n\rvert
 \hat{a}_1\hat{a}_2
\lvert j,k\rangle
\\
&=
\alpha\delta_{nk}\delta_{mj}m
+
\beta\sqrt{m+1}\sqrt{n+1}\delta_{m+1,j}\delta_{n+1,k}\,.
\end{align}
We put this back in the sum, yielding
\begin{align}
\hat{O} &=
\sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j,k=0}^{\infty}\lvert m,n\rangle
\left(m\alpha\delta_{nk}\delta_{mj}
+
\beta\sqrt{m+1}\sqrt{n+1}\delta_{m+1,j}\delta_{n+1,k}\right)
\langle j,k\rvert
\\&=
\alpha\sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j,k=0}^{\infty}
m\delta_{nk}\delta_{mj}
\lvert m,n\rangle\langle j,k\rvert
+
\beta
\sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j,k=0}^{\infty}
\sqrt{m+1}\sqrt{n+1}\delta_{m+1,j}\delta_{n+1,k}
\lvert m,n\rangle\langle j,k\rvert
\\&=
\alpha\sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty}
m\lvert m,n\rangle\langle m,n\rvert
+
\beta
\sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty}
\sqrt{m+1}\sqrt{n+1}
\lvert m+1,n+1\rangle\langle j,k\rvert
\,.
\end{align}
And that's about as far as you can go with it!

Comment: Thanks so much @march, this clears up all of my confusions!  Although I think in those last steps you accidentally made the annihilation operators create.

Answer (score 2):

This is but the standard infinite-dimensional matrix tensor product. [Review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators#Matrix_representation) the Fock space with just one type of creation and annihilation operators,
$$
\hat a= \sum_n  \sqrt{n} ~|n-1\rangle \langle n|, \\
\hat a ^\dagger= \sum_n  \sqrt{n+1} ~ |n+1\rangle \langle n|.
$$

Now tensor two types of oscillators as you did:
$$
\hat O= \sum_{m,n}\bigl (\alpha m ~|m,n\rangle \langle m,n|+ \beta \sqrt{mn} ~| m-1,n-1\rangle \langle  m,n|\bigr )~~.
$$